# A problem with logging in and file handling in a PHP login script

Tags: php

Hello i have a problem when logging in and a resource #5 id error is returned.
1. When i login from localhost:80/ i login fine and there are no errors.
2. When i login from localhost/index.php for some reason it gives a resource id #5.

Why does this happen and how should i fix it?
The code is below:

```
require("connectuser.php");
require("activeuser.php");
session_start();
$makesure = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
$makesure16 = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
$applications = mysql_real_escape_string($makesure);
$mytabletop = mysql_real_escape_string($makesure16);
$encryptpassword = md5($makesure16);
$sqlstatement = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE emailaddress = '$makesure' AND password =     '$encryptpassword'";
$whatever = mysql_query($sqlstatement) or die("Unable to Sign In");
$appstore = mysql_num_rows($whatever) or die($whatever);
```

What do i do to fix it though...

Comment: Can you describe more clearly at which point you get the "resource ID" thing exactly?

Comment: I get the resource id error #5 when i am doing mysql_num_rows($whatever);

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

Remove the  `or die...` part behind

```
$appstore = mysql_num_rows($whatever) or die($whatever);
```

Long answer: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302259/script-breaking-below-mysql-queries-but-no-error-being-given).

Answer (score 1):

`die` function can't take the mysql resource `$whatever`.  Try changing the error message to something like `$appstore = mysql_num_rows($whatever) or die(mysql_error());`

**Edit**:

```
$appstore = mysql_num_rows($whatever);
if($appstore === FALSE) die(mysql_error);
```

Comment: This won't work either, because the script will die if `mysql_num_rows()` returns `0`.

Comment: Gotcha. Needs to strictly equal false to indicate an actual error.

Comment: Why does the login script work from localhost:80 and not from index.php!!!!!!